# How to remove text from a list?

Tags: scala, list

I am working with a `List` and I would like to remove the field name and add quotes to results. What I have is this that the code below returns:

> Date: Wed, 28 Mar 2001 08:07:00 -0800 (PST)

The expected output would be:

> "Wed, 28 Mar 2001 08:07:00 -0800 (PST)"

I have this code, but how can I add `"` around the results and remove the "Date :"

```
val toField = lines.dropWhile(line => !line.startsWith("To: ")).takeWhile(line  => !line.startsWith("Subject: "))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.substring(7)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the field names are the same (i.e. "Date:"), you could use `substring` on all the list elements. Assuming a simple list with two elements:

```
val toField = List("Date: Wed, 28 Mar 2001 08:07:00 -0800 (PST)", "Date: Fri, 30 Mar 2001 08:07:00 -0800 (PST)")
val dates = toField.map(f => "\"" + f.substring(6) + "\"")
```

At the same time the quotes are added as well.

However, if the field name can be of different lengths, using `split` would be more appropriate:

```
val res = toField.map(f => "\"" + f.split(":").tail.mkString(":").trim() + "\"")
```

This will split the string on `"` and drop the head elements.